# Which data members do the child class use in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Ball b=new Ball();
        System.out.println(b.getName());
     }
}

class Shape{
    private String name;
    Shape(){
        name="Shape";
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

class Ball extends Shape{
    private String name;
    public Ball(){
        name="Ball";
    }
}
```

Why am I getting output as:"Shape" instead of "Ball"?

I am getting same result even if I change

```
private String name;
```

to

```
public String name;
```

in both the `Shape` and `Ball` classes.

Comment: `name` is `private`. It exists independently is each `class`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Even if `name` was public, you would still have two separate fields. These are just two fields that happen to have the same name in two different classes.

Answer (score 3):

There are two `name` fields in Ball object - one defined in `Ball` class and one in `Shape` class.

When you create field with same name in child class, you [hide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) parent class field. Try to avoid it in your code. Normally you can still access parent field with *super* keyword like `super.name`, but since your fields are private you can't do that.

Method `Shape#getName` returns field `name` from its class. Fields in Java do not override parent fields like methods do, so `Shape.name` is not anyhow substituted with `Ball.name`.

Review this code to see how reference type determines the field to use

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
println ball.name;  // prints Ball, because reference type if Ball

Shape shape = ball; // this is same ball object
println shape.name; // prints Shape, because reference type is Shape

println ball.getName(); // prints Shape - getter in Shape class can only see Shape fields
```

If you add getter in `Ball` class then method calls will always return 'Ball'

```
println ball.getName();  // will print Ball
println shape.getName(); // will print Ball
```

Comment: I am getting "Shape" as output even if the `name` is changed from "private" to "public"

Comment: @TryinHard But `Shape` only knows about `name` declared in `Shape`. It always accesses this field. Fields are not virtual, i.e. `Shape.name` and `Ball.name` are two separate fields. If you make `name` protected in `Shape` and drop `name` from `Ball` completely, you get the result you intended (but it's not good OO to do so).

Comment: @TryinHard I tried to explain how overriding a method differs from hiding a field

Comment: @AdamSkywalker `((Shape) ball).getName()` returns `Ball.name` only if you also override `getName()` in `Ball`. Otherwise you access `Shape.getName()` which has no knowledge of `Ball.name`.

Comment: @dhke yes, I forgot to mention method overriding

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic *overriding by name* for fields. If you have a field in a class and a field with the same name in a subclass, you have two different fields.

`Shape.name` and `Ball.name` are completely separate entities. If you set both fields `public`, you get:

```
Shape s = new Ball();
s.getName();   // => returns "shape"
s.name         // yields "shape", because you are accessing a class of type `Shape`.
((Ball)s).name // yields "ball", because you are accessing a class of type `Ball`
```

At this point `Ball` in fact has two different `name` fields: The one it inherits from `Shape` and the one declared in the `Ball` class itself.

If you access `name` inside `Ball`, however, you get the first one determined by symbol lookup rules, which is `Ball.name`. If `Shape.name` is `protected` or `public`, it will be available by `super.name`. Note again: There are *two separate name fields*, one for each class. They just happen to have the same field name, but are otherwise completely separate.

The same lookup rules apply also for `Shape`: When `Shape.getName()` is compiled, it tries to find a field named `name` *at compile time* and uses the one it finds, which is the only one available at this time: the one in `Shape`. The lookup is static.

However, if `Shape.name` is private, you cannot access it from the `Ball` class directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all inheritance passes from superclass to subclass, including instance variables and methods.

Meaning, if you wanted to "call a superclass method" with "subclass parameters", you simply create an object in the subclass and call your method.

Because the unique method named `getName()` is located in youe superclass, when invok the method `getName()`, firstly searchedin subclass when it's not there it search in superclass.
For this you have: `Shape` instead of `Ball`:

Answer (score 0):

when you create the new ball, In the ball constructor the first thing that is executed implicitly is the super constructor, without arguments. This means that the shape constructor is executed setting name="shape". Then because of the fact that the getName method is not overloaded, you get the "shape" value.